# EC2 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-ec2, shiny

I tried to encrypt my shiny server on an Amazon EC2 server (Ubuntu) today and I modified my firewalls a little by

```
ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

however, somehow, the port 22 is closed and I cannot connect my instance using ssh anymore. I learned that I have to ufw port 22 again but I just cannot connect my instance at all. Is there any methods I can solve this?

By the way, I still have port 22 in my security group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly allow port 22 too otherwise you will be blocked.

To fix your issue you can follow steps listed [here](https://u.osu.edu/walujo.1/2017/04/21/how-to-fix-ec2-instance-when-you-accidentally-block-port-22/) or If you are able to create a new instance instead just kill this one and spin a new one and ensure you also allow port 22

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created a new one.